# How to set default to custom Index Scopes in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In one of my RoR projects, I'm using [ActiveAdmin (1.4.3)](https://github.com/activeadmin) and [Discard](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard) gems.
I have created two custom scopes like this:

```
scope ('Kept') { |scope| scope.kept }
scope ('Discarded') { |scope| scope.discarded }
```

I want to set one of them ('Kept') as default scope that will be applied when a user visits index page for the resource (and I don't like [the idea of adding default_scope](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard#default-scope) in my model)

Here's the snippet from [Active Admin documentation](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html):

```
scope :all, default: true

# assumes the model has a scope called ':active'
scope :active

# renames model scope ':leaves' to ':subcategories'
scope "Subcategories", :leaves

# Dynamic scope name
scope ->{ Date.today.strftime '%A' }, :published_today

# custom scope not defined on the model
scope("Inactive") { |scope| scope.where(active: false) }

# conditionally show a custom controller scope
scope "Published", if: -> { current_admin_user.can? :manage, Posts } do |posts|
  posts.published
end
```

It shows that there is optional `default` argument that, in fact, works as intended for simple scopes with a symbol.

I tried to add this to my custom scope like this:

```
scope ('Kept', default: true) { |scope| scope.kept }
```

but I'm getting syntax errors.

it looks like it only works for scopes with a symbol, not with string and optional block. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Remove space before bracket, it should be `scope('Kept', default: true) { |scope| scope.kept }`

Comment: It works now. So it was a simple mistake on my part. Thank you @Vasilisa